# What is the equivalent tensorflow operation of this numpy array operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, for example, `y_pred` is a numpy array and I want this operation.

```
result = []
for i in y_pred:
    i = np.where(i == i.max(), 1, 0)
    result.append(i)
```

The maximum number of each row in `y_pred` will become `1` and the rest will become `0`.

How can I implement this operation if y_pred is a tensor?

Comment: Edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a vectorized function already available that does all these things together.

Assume this is your array.

```
a = tf.Variable([[10,11,12,13],
             [13,14,16,15],
             [18,16,17,15],
             [0,4,3,2]], name='a')
```

`top = tf.nn.top_k(a,1)` gives the indices of the maximum values in each row. Now we start with *ones* `acopy = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((4,4),tf.int32), name='acopy')`  which is the same shape as the original array.

After that we just stitch the rows together after replacing zeros in the positions where maximum values were found.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable([[10,11,12,13],
                 [13,14,16,15],
                 [18,16,17,15],
                 [0,4,3,2]], name='a')

acopy = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((4,4),tf.int32), name='acopy')

top = tf.nn.top_k(a,1)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

values,indices = sess.run(top)

shapeofa = a.eval(sess).shape

print(indices)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(0, shapeofa[0] ) :
    oldrow = tf.gather(acopy, i)
    index = tf.squeeze(indices[i])
    b = sess.run( tf.equal(index, 0) )
    if not b  :
        o = oldrow[0:index]
        newrow = tf.concat([o, tf.constant([1])], axis=0)
        c = sess.run(tf.equal(index, (tf.size(oldrow) - 1)))
        if not c:
            newrow = tf.concat([newrow, oldrow[(index+1):(tf.size(oldrow))]], axis=0)
    else :
        o1 = oldrow[1:tf.size(oldrow)]
        newrow = tf.concat([tf.constant([1]), o1], axis=0)
    acopy = tf.scatter_update(acopy, i, newrow)
    print(sess.run(acopy))
```

The output is this.

> [[0 0 0 1]
>
> [0 0 1 0]
>
> [1 0 0 0]
>
> [0 1 0 0]]

You may test this yourself.

Comment: Is that useful for you ? If you test it and find it useful you could either upvote or accept the answer.